# Html Special character for fractions

Tags: html

When I write `&frac45;` in my html document and display it in browser it shows 4/5 in browser but, `&frac69;` is rendered as " &frac69; " in plain text inspite of 6/9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

&frac69; doesnt translate because it is not a part of the entity schema.
Actually &frac69; is 2/3 try using `&frac23;` it will work

Comment: what about &frac37; ? that is too rendered as it is.

Comment: Because it is not actually part of the entity schema

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/numbers/ only the ones listed here will translate

Comment: &#8532;  is for 2/3 try it

Answer (score 2):

Since you prefer to display in numerator/denominator format means fraction then, use  `&frasl;` in conjunction with HTML `sup` and `sub` tags.

**Example:**

```
<sup>6</sup> &frasl; <sub>9</sub>
```

output:-

```
 6/9
```